# Xamarin.Forms Texts not displayed on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created an app in Xamarin.Forms and did the development on my android device, since I did not have neither an iPhone nor an MAC on my hand.
The app is working perfectly on android and now I wanted to port it to iOS.

My initial issue was, that my layout is completely broken on iOS and that none of my texts are displayed.
In order to make sure, that my fonts and images aren't the problem, I therefore created a simple ContentPage, only containing a stack layout with some controls; The issue with text not being displayed persists (independent of device or simulator and dark mode on or off).
I then created a blank project and uploaded it to my iPhone - which is working fine. So VS is also not the problem.

This is the output of the application running on my iPhone:

```
Diese Debug-Engine unterstützt keine Ausnahmebedingungen. Die Bedingungen werden ignoriert.
2022-11-11 13:27:18.287 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339689] Xamarin.iOS: Successfully received USB connection from the IDE on port 10000, fd: 6

2022-11-11 13:27:18.289 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339689] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'

2022-11-11 13:27:18.289 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Thread started:  #3
2022-11-11 13:27:20.277 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content

2022-11-11 13:27:20.279 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] App path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/AutoLeveling.iOS.exe

2022-11-11 13:27:20.280 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:20.280 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:20.281 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'AutoLeveling' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:20.282 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'AutoLeveling' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:20.283 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:20.283 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/AutoLeveling.iOS.exe
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/AutoLeveling.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
2022-11-11 13:27:21.099 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] AppDelegate name: AppDelegate

Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
2022-11-11 13:27:21.173 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Plugin.BLE.Abstractions' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:21.173 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'Plugin.BLE.Abstractions' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Plugin.BLE.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
2022-11-11 13:27:21.236 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'IHttpMachine' (culture: '')

2022-11-11 13:27:21.237 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1051:339685] Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'IHttpMachine' (culture: '')

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/HttpMachine.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/IHttpMachine.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Crc32.NET.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/275C48C5-8CFF-4DA2-9A04-E1DA18C3D2EB/AutoLeveling.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A37B99A-F5CB-4395-A28E-DE71CBE31452/Documents/AutoLeveling.iOS.content/Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
```

This is my Test pages code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AutoLeveling.Views.TestView">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,100,0,0">
        <Label Text="Wazzzuuuup" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" Background="red" MinimumWidthRequest="30" MinimumHeightRequest="30" />
        <Button Text="Btn" FontSize="Caption" WidthRequest="100" />
        <Label Text="Testlabel" />
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red"  Padding="10" >
            <Label Text="nested testlabel" TextColor="Black"  Background="blue" Padding="0"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button  Text="Testbutton" Clicked="Button_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is it's look on the simulator (same as on real device):
[image]

Am I missing something? Did anyone experience a similar issue? I really don't know how to get this working...

EDIT:///
I've narrowed it down. When I add `FontFamily=""` to the labels, the text is displayed. So there seems to be an issue with the fonts.
I've added the Fonts to the Resources/Fonts folder of the iOS Project and added them in Info.plist - they are already as ExportFont in the multi platform project - none works

EDIT2:///
I narrowed it down to an issue with the fonts on iOS. I created a minimal example. Maybe someone can find the issue...
[Zipped Project](https://easyupload.io/gltv1r)

Comment: Why are you using `MinimumWidthRequest` and `MinimumHeightRequest` here? What happens if you only use `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`? Have you tried making the label higher? If the text doesn't fit into the label, it might not get rendered at all.

Comment: More information about `MinimumHeightRequest` can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.minimumheightrequest?view=xamarin-forms I think you should really just use `HeightRequest` instead and make the label large enough to accommodate the text

Comment: I just tried some properties if they change something, ended up with `MinimumWidthRequest` and `MinimumHeightRequest`.
I added `WidthRequest = 100` to the labels, now the Red (respective Blue) background is rendered, but still no text is displayed

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the fonts - see above edit :(

Comment: Instead of zipping the project, it would be better to create a small GitHub repo with a reproducible example. Also, can you show how you've set up your fonts in your project?

Comment: Typo. You didn't show the most important line: your reference to FontFamily.
In the zipped project, it is `FontFamily="Gotham-Bold"`.
But the font itself is `GothamBold`. Remove `-`.

Comment: I cannot open the zipped project you provided. I used the test page code you provided in the thread to display fine in the iOS simulator and did not reproduce your problem. You said 'When I add FontFamily="" to the labels, the text is displayed', could you provide your code for setting fonts?

Comment: Okay, so I narrowed the problem down to the Gotham Font. I tried using Montserrat, which is more or less the same... and that works. It seems to me, that the Gotham ttf file has some issues in height calculation with iOS.
Can somebody confirm?

Comment: To confirm your iOS font family name, on macOS open your .ttf using Font Book and the name that macOS/iOS will use is the one in the title bar of the app.

Comment: Hi @DongzhiWang-MSFT, yes this was one of the problems. On iOS the font name is simply "Gotham" and the weight is "Bold" or "Medium", Xamarin does not expose the Medium weight so I would have to write custom Renderers in order to expose this property and set the weight.
It's so annoying, that once again microsofts documentation is simply wrong. In the docs it says that using the "Alias" Property should do the trick...
Also macOS seems to have a problem with the medium font, it is totally squished on mac. I'll stick with montserrat because that seems to work